# Passing context from MainActivity to other Class for System services

Tags: java, android, service, system, android-context

I want to clean my Main activity class a bit and transfer some code to other class to make my code a bit more easier to read. 
I got a situation like this

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getData("2B1A4D3C");
     }
    public void getData(String Hex) {
        Static staticClass = new Static();
           if (staticClass.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this) == true) {
                  staticClass.setData(response);
           }
    }
}
```

2nd class

```
class Static extends AppCompatActivity {
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = 
            connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if ( activeNetworkInfo != null ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I pass contex like this -> isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this) I got a crash. And get an error

> System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

What is a proper way to pass context?

Comment: onCreate has to be called in the Static class before you can call the connectivity manager. Don't extend AppCompatActivity, and use the context instance instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
        context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Otherwise that call will actually be `Static.this.getSystemService(...)` and since the `Static` instance was created by you and not the system, it isn't a valid `Context`.

But in this case, I don't see any reason for the `Static` class to extend `AppCompatActivity` so you should probably remove that.

Comment: Thanks that's explains everything what I need.

Comment: @ekavet I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you have made your Static class an activity without an onCreate method. Instead of that make it a simple Java class and pass the context to isNetworkAvailable method via function parameter.